# How do I get orders using store code/store id using Magento rest api

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I am trying fetch orders using store_id but I am not getting response from Magento rest API which I am using. So far, I have tried follwowing URL patterns to check the response but none of them worked.

```
/rest/V1/orders/{store_id}
/rest/default/V1/orders/
/rest/{store_id}/V1/orders/
/rest/all/V1/orders/
```

After trying above URL patterns I got error message or least json output, but don't if that is what I desire.

Error message:

```
{'message': 'Specified request cannot be processed.'}
```

So, as a store_id I am using `1` as id parameter. I want to get the orders by specific store .

I did go thorugh Magneto API documentation but unable to find clue on this. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Ty to use store code, not store id.

Comment: How do I get store code?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the store code, which you can get from the admin console: **Stores** > **All Stores** then the store code is shown underneath the store in parentheses.